# After ssh to remote server, it freezes, if I type commands like "top", "htop", "screen -r screenname", "pipenv shell"

Tags: networking, 22.04, ssh, freeze, scp

**I try to connect to a remote server, to train a machine learning model. With my ubuntu laptop,**

1. I can ssh to the server
2. I can not scp any file. It starts but freezes at 0 percent and 0kbit/sec speed
3. After I ssh, if I want to use 'screen -r screen_name' command, it freezes. If I run "pipenv shell" it freezes. If I run "top" or "htop" it freezes.

**With my old windows laptop, with the same login credentials, I can do all.**

**What I have tried:**

1. I have checked ssh configurations and there is nothing to not permit scp
2. No firewall
3. I have formatted the laptop. The problem still exists.